# Prevent click event on mouseup and mouseup event on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I've created a dragbar , which will increase and decrease container width on dragging and on click it will contract/expand. But whenever I'm trying to drag it click event is triggering and dragbar is contracting. I'm using backbone.js and using the code below.

```
events: {
    'click .sideNavBar': 'toggleHeadersSection',
    'mousedown #dragBar': 'increaseDragBarWidth',
    'mouseup #dragBar': 'decreaseDragBarWidth',
    'click #dragBar': 'toggleHeadersSection',
},

increaseDragBarWidth: function (event){
    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
        $('.clinical-data-accordion').css("width",event.pageX+2);
    });

},

decreaseDragBarWidth: function (event){
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
},
toggleHeadersSection: function(event){
       let clinicalDetailSection = this.$el.find("#clinicalDetailSection");
       let isHidden = $(clinicalDetailSection).hasClass('isHidden');
       this.displayHeadersSection(isHidden);
   
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/djq2ec7r/19/) with some images that you can drag and click. (it is pure js)

There a click is separated from a drag by checking the time difference of mouse down and up events.

```
let timeDelta;

function startDrag(e) { // mouse up
    timeDelta = Date.now(); // get current millis
    ...

function stopDrag() { // mouse down
    if (typeof drag == "undefined") return;

    if (drag) {
        if (Date.now() - timeDelta > 150) { // we dragged
    ...
```

If you hold the mouse down for more than 150ms, it is not counted as a click. If you add that check to your click event, it should work.